# why myscrollview not scrolling on android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, scrollview

i have an layout with code like this, i want create layout like profile on isntagram app. but i don't know why my scrollview, not working at all

this is my code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/containerProfile"
tools:context=".ui.profile.ProfileActivity">

    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rl1">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/myprofile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_Layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/myprofile"/>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_Pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tab_Layout">
        </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

can someone explain why? this my full xml code https://pastebin.com/XwgsA2cT

Comment: I did try your full XML code. I think it's working fine, you can try it on Landscape view. It show the scroll, I think on Portrait mode it doesn't have enough content to show a scroll. Also please use NestedScrollView on this one since you have other views inline with your scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Try using nested scroll view instead

Comment: change relative layout to constraint layout and try

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView doesn't work on Multiple child Layout. Wrap all your Layout inside a Relative/Linear Layout and then wrap that layout with ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Try NestedScrollView instead, it will work.
Make `NestedScrollView` parent viewgroup.  Also make sure its closing tag is at same level..
In your case, you have mismatch in your opening and closing tags.. You started with `RelativeLayout` while closing with `</ScrollView>`.
Your parent viewgroup is `<RelativeLayout>` make it `<NestedScrollView>` also close your parent viewgroup with `</NestedScrollView>`

**Update**

```
<NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/containerProfile"
tools:context=".ui.profile.ProfileActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rl1">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/myprofile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_Layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/myprofile"/>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_Pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tab_Layout">
        </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
    </RelativeLayout>
</NestedScrollView>
```

**Note** - Make sure to update your view **ids**

Comment: @user12134577 Check I have updated the answer. Make sure to change your **view ids** else it wont work.